# When raising to a power and tetrating, which comes first? Is $^24^3$ equal to $(^24)^3$, or to $^2(4^3)$?

Tags: tetration

I know tetration isn't quite an used operation, but anyway, what if it were featured in an expression?

For example, what does $^24^3$ mean? Is it $(^24)^3=(4^4)^3=4^{12}$ or is it $^2(4^3)=^2{64}=64^{64}$?

Answer (score 2):

If I *personally* had to interpret it, I would rather it be $(^24)^3,$ so that tetration would bind more closely to the input than exponentiation does.

However, the real answer is: it's ambiguous.  There is no general convention to determine an order of operations involving tetration, so if you use it, you ought to use parentheses to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 0):

The only version I've seen of $ \;^h b^x $ was
$$ a_h = \;^h b^x \implies \\\
 a_0=x  \\\
 a_1=b^x \\\
 a_2  = b^{a_1} = b^{b^x} = \;^2 b^x\\\
 \vdots \\\
 a_h = b^{a_{h-1}} = \underset{h \text{ times}}{\underbrace{ b^{ \cdots b^{b^x}}}} = \;^h b^x \\\
$$
Isn't this in wikipedia?

---

p.s.: $(\;^24)^3 $ would be $ (4^4)^3 = 4^{3 \cdot 4} = 16777216
 $
and $\;^2(4^3) $ would be $ (4^3)^{(4^3)} = 4^{3 \cdot 4^3 } = 394020061963944792... 6627990306816$ with 116 digits....
while my proposed interpretation would be $ 4^{(4^3)} =340282366920938463463374607431768211456$ having 39 digits

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is $(^2 4)^3$. Similarly, to how multiplication is done before addition in the order of operations, exponentiation is done before multiplication. Therefore, I say that tetration is done before exponentiation.

However, just like in an expression with an order of evaluation that is hard to see, I would say to use parentheses to clarify what to do first.

Answer (score 0):

Higher order operators are right-associative so I'd read it as $^{2}(4^3)$ which evaluates to $64^{64}$